# How can i create a Terminal in Unity that gives Input for a Docker Container?

Tags: python, c#, docker, unity-game-engine, terminal

I want to execute Python Code in Unity using Docker, but i cant use the input command.
Is there any way i can create a Terminal that allows me to use the -it Tag in Unity?
Thank you in advance!!

Here is my Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class DockerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField pythonCodeInputField;
    public Button runButton;
    public SimplifiedConsole simplifiedConsole;
    private Button TerminalButton;

void Start()
    {
        runButton.onClick.AddListener(ExecutePythonCodeInDocker);
    }
    private void GetOrInstantiateConsoleModule()
    {
        
        simplifiedConsole = FindObjectOfType<SimplifiedConsole>();
        if (simplifiedConsole == null)
        {
            TerminalButton.onClick.Invoke();
            simplifiedConsole = FindObjectOfType<SimplifiedConsole>();
        }
    }


    private void ExecutePythonCodeInDocker()
    {
        string pythonCode = pythonCodeInputField.text;
        GetOrInstantiateConsoleModule();
        // Save the Python code to a temporary file
        string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllText(tempFileName, pythonCode);

        // Copy the file to the Docker container
        ProcessStartInfo copyInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        copyInfo.FileName = "docker";
        copyInfo.Arguments = $"cp \"{tempFileName}\" pyc_container:/tmp/code.py";
        copyInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        copyInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process copyProcess = new Process();
        copyProcess.StartInfo = copyInfo;
        copyProcess.Start();
        copyProcess.WaitForExit();

        // Execute the Python code in the Docker container
        ProcessStartInfo execInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        execInfo.FileName = "docker";
        execInfo.Arguments = "exec -it pyc_container python /tmp/code.py";
        execInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        execInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        execInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        execInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        execInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process execProcess = new Process();
        execProcess.StartInfo = execInfo;
        execProcess.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
        execProcess.ErrorDataReceived += Process_ErrorDataReceived;
        execProcess.Start();
        execProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        execProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

        // Clean up the temporary file
        File.Delete(tempFileName);
    }

private void Process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        // Call the method in the SimplifiedConsole class
        simplifiedConsole.UpdateOutputText(e.Data + "\n");
    }
}

private void Process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        // Call the method in the SimplifiedConsole class
        simplifiedConsole.UpdateOutputText(e.Data + "\n");
    }
}
```

I already tried to create a PTY but i cant get it to work. I always get "The input device is not TTY".